# Alternatives to Meyer Windows as Curvelets?

Tags: image-processing, wavelet, multi-scale-analysis

I am looking for alternative to Meyer window functions ([Section 4.1](http://num.math.uni-goettingen.de/plonka/pdfs/CurveletReviewshort.pdf)) from which one can define a curvelet system.

Are there any similar window functions which would be as easy to implement?